# LDAP BlueSpice for MediaWiki

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, mediawiki

I confused to make integrating login system in BlueSpice. I have code like this to make BlueSpice connect to LDAP server. But it doesn't work. This is my code in `LocalSettings.php`

```
require_once("$IP/extensions/LdapAuthentication/LdapAuthentication.php");
$wgAuth = new LdapAuthenticationPlugin();

$wgLDAPDomainNames = array('mydomain');
$wgLDAPServerNames = array('mydomain' => 'merahputih.domain.co.id');
$wgLDAPSearchStrings = array('mydomain' => 'domain\USER-NAME');
$wgLDAPUseLocal = false;
$wgLDAPEncryptionType = array('mydomain' => 'clear');
$wgMinimalPasswordLength = 1;
$wgLDAPBaseDNs = array('mydomain' => 'dc=domain,dc=co,dc=id');
$wgLDAPSearchAttributes = array('mydomain' => 'sAMAccountName');
$wgLDAPRetrievePrefs = array('mydomain' => 'true');
$wgLDAPDebug = 3;
$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;
$wgLDAPOption = array('mydomain' => array(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,1));
$wgLDAPPort = array('mydomain' => 389);
```

And I have an auth realm when I get the domain from the customer. I don't know about that and I read any references but still not found.

Comment: Define "doesn't work": what are the symptoms, what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried my code but I stil can't login using my LDAP account.

Comment: You may want to share your experience in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/AuthManager so that such a job is made easier in the future.